# How to display results from two queries onto MS Chart Object using Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am not sure if someone has done this before but I have searched and searched to learn but not getting anywhere.
I have two queries which are currently producing the `RowSource` of two MS Chart Objects in a clustered column chart. It works but, since the 
datasets are similar, I wanted to display the two datasets on a single Chart with two series since the x axis values from both queries are similar.
This would show `ItemNames` in the x axis and `SumOfNetSales` for the corresponding series on the y axis.

`qryChartSummer` looks like:

```
+================+===================+
+  ItemNames     +    SumOfNetSales  +     
+================+===================+
+  Cups          +  £2000.40         +
+----------------+-------------------+
+  Plates        +  £4500.32         +
+----------------+-------------------+
+  Spoons        +  £2300.12         +
+----------------+-------------------+
+  Soda glasses  +  £3200.30         +
+----------------+-------------------+
+  Soda glasses  +  £2500.00         +
+----------------+-------------------+
```

`qryChartWinter` looks like:

```
+================+===================+
+  ItemNames     +    SumOfNetSales  +     
+================+===================+
+  Spoons        +  £3200.00         +
+----------------+-------------------+
+  Soda glasses  +  £1200.00         +
+----------------+-------------------+
+  Cups          +  £4300.30         +
+----------------+-------------------+
```

The RowSource for the two charts are currently as:

```
qryChartSummerRowSource = "SELECT [ItemNames],Sum([SumOfNetPrice]) AS [SumOfSumOfNetPrice] FROM 
[qryChartSummer] GROUP BY [ItemName];"
qryChartWinterRowSource = "SELECT [ItemNames],Sum([SumOfNetPrice]) AS [SumOfSumOfNetPrice] FROM 
[qryChartWinter] GROUP BY [ItemName];"

Me.ChartSummer.RowSource = qryChartSummerRowSource
Me.ChartWinter.RowSource = qryChartWinterRowSource
```

If I am to create another Chart Object named `ChartAll` how do I display these two sets of data onto `ChartAll`? Thank you in advance for all your help.

Edit:

Main table contains all item lines and looks like:
`+================+===================+================+=============+
 +  ItemNames     +    NetSales       +   DateOfSales  +   Period    +
 +================+===================+================+=============+
 +  Cups          +   £66.80          +   02/11/2019   +   Autumn    +
 +----------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------+
 +  Cups          +   £34.34          +   12/12/2019   +   Winter     +
 +----------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------+
 +  Cups          +   £56.26          +   03/01/2019   +   Winter    +
 +----------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------+
 +  Cups          +   £34.34          +   04/02/2019   +   Winter    +
 +----------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------+
 +  Plates        +   £50.32          +   03/11/2019   +   Autumn    +
 +----------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------+
 +  Spoons        +   £24.12          +   08/03/2019   +   Spring    +
 +----------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------+
 +  Soda glasses  +   £52.30          +   07/07/2019   +   Summer    +
 +----------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------+
 +  Soda glasses  +   £34.00          +   03/08/2019   +   Summer    +
 +----------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------+
 +  Plates        +   £51.30          +   03/10/2019   +   Autumn    +
 +----------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------+
 +  Plates        +   £65.32          +   06/09/2019   +   Autumn    +
 +----------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------+
 +  Spoons        +   £50.12          +   08/03/2019   +   Spring    +
 +----------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------+`

Comment: Do you have a master table of all possible ItemNames you could join these two queries to?

Comment: @June7 yes I do. Don't know how to join the queries though.

Comment: Join queries same way as joining tables. These queries have same table as source? Maybe should build CROSSTAB query instead of two grouping queries. Edit question to show sample raw data.

Comment: @June7 The table is big and contains individual item lines. Please consider revised question.

Comment: Again, suggest you explore CROSSTAB query.

Comment: I am having trouble dealing with the date field on a crosstab query.

Comment: What would the trouble be? If displayed dates have international structure, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: @June7 I see, I have:

`TRANSFORM Sum(qryAll.NetSales) AS SumOfNetSales
SELECT qryAll.ItemName, qryAll.Period
FROM qryAll
GROUP BY qryAll.ItemName, qryAll.Period
PIVOT qryAll.Period;` Is it possible to apply a WHERE Clause on the DateOfSales field to filter out the previous business year and the current business year? If This is not too much to ask?

`WHERE DateDiff('m', [DateOfSales], DateSerial(Year(Date()), 1, 1)) Between 3 And -9 `for current business year and

`WHERE DateDiff('m', [DateOfSales], DateSerial(Year(Date()) - 1, 1, 1)) Between 3 And -9` for the previous business year

Comment: What happens when you try? If you want only current year records, then maybe `WHERE Year([DateOfSales])=Year(Date())`. More about CROSSTAB http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html

Comment: @June7 I am still getting problems with the statement. I have created a query which deals with the current and previous years which works fine. But the problem now is incorporating the Where clause in the Statement. `TRANSFORM Sum([NetSales]) AS [SumOfNetSales] SELECT [Period] FROM [qryForAll] WHERE ([MonthDiffCurrentYear] BETWEEN -8 AND 4) AND ([MonthDiffPreviousYear] BETWEEN -7 AND 4) As TheYear GROUP BY [Period] PIVOT [TheYear];`

Comment: Edit question with all relevant info, including SQL for all queries involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a query called `qryAll` using:
`SELECT ItemName, NetSales, Period FROM tblAllSales ORDER BY ItemName ASC`

Then on the form Load event:

```
Me.ChartAll.RowSource = "TRANSFORM Sum([NetSales]) AS [SumOfNetPrice] SELECT [ItemName] FROM [qryAll] GROUP BY [ItemName] PIVOT [Period];"
```

The `[Period]` items are shown as the series on the MS Chart Object as expected.